# Check that combinations not in list

Tags: python

Simplified – have a dict:

```
flags = { 'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 0, 'e': 1, 'f': 1 }
```

Now there are certain combinations that are not allowed:

```
no_combo = [
    ['a', 'c'],
    ['b', 'd', 'e']
]
```

How best to validate I do not have combinations in `flags` that are not allowed according to `no_combo`?

From example above we have a conflict because both `b` and `e` are set to `1`.

```
set_flags = [k for k in flags if flags[k]]
```

gives:

```
['b', 'c', 'e', 'f']
```

which is in conflict with restriction of no combinations of `no_combo[1]`:

```
['b', 'd', 'e']
```

Now to cross check with `no_combo`?

I have this:

```
for combo in no_combo:
    if len([f for f in combo if f in set_flags]) > 1:
        print('fail on', combo)
```

But wondering if there is a better way to solve it?

Is there for example some similar method to `all()` and `any()` for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
flags = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 0, 'e': 1, 'f': 1}

no_combo = [
    ['a', 'c'],
    ['b', 'd', 'e']
]

for combo in no_combo:
    if sum(flags.get(c, 0) for c in combo) > 1:
        print('fail on', combo)
```

**Output**

```
fail on ['b', 'd', 'e']
```

This saves you the list creation (the one you use in the call to len). Note that this assumes the values of the flags are 0 or 1.

You could also use a while loop and break it as soon as the sum reaches 2. For example:

```
for combo in no_combo:
    total = 0
    for c in combo:
        total += flags.get(c, 0)
        if total > 1:
            print('fail on', combo)
            break
```

It is a little bit cumbersome but avoids iterating over the whole list, so it saves you some time.

Comment: Sweet :) , this looks very promising. Knew there was a better way ❤

Comment: In my code the flags are only `0` or `1`. But one could say: `sum(flags.get(c, 0) > 0 for c in combo)` - as in ` > 0` if this should be an issue. The True / False's convert to 0 / 1

Comment: Sorry for the noise – but not sure what you mean by using a while loop. It works as is, - but curious.

Comment: The thing is you don't need to to do the whole sum, only *while* is less than two, so you could do a while loop and keep a counter variable. I hope is clearer now.

Comment: @user3342816 Added an example to my answer.

Comment: Thank you and sorry again for the noise. I got hung up in a literal *while*.